# Is there is a way to count a characters in a mention in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

**My current code**

```
let person = message.mentions.users.first()
let characterInAMention = // I don't know what i've need to write here.
```

I don't know what i need to write

Comment: Are you trying to count characters in the entire message that contains a mention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `.length`

E.g:

```js
let person = message.mentions.users.first()
let characterInAMention = person.username.length //as Zsolt mentioned below
```

I would recommend learning Javascript to a good degree before starting coding bots, and do try to consult the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) before asking.

Comment: Yeah, you teaching me 20 minutes after i learn it, LOL

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer is accepted. There is no way it works; `person` is either `undefined` (no mention), or an object (`User`) that doesn't have a `length` property. If there is no mention, it throws a TypeError. If there is a mention, `person.length` is `undefined`. Maybe `person.username.length` would work but what if the member has a nickname. In that case the mentioned name's length will be different. Anyway, I'm not even sure what OP is asking, the question should be updated.

Comment: Oh god you're right, I will fix it now, my mistake